# Bicubic/bilinear interpolation in R

Tags: r, interpolation

I have a data set of `x,y,z` data and I'd like to do a bicubic interpolation. x and y are spatial coordinates and z is a temperature.

Below there are two images. The first one is a (gnuplot) plot of my dataset and the second one is an interpolated version (`set pm3d interpolate 10,10`).

Now I'd like to do this interpolation in R but I want a matrix of values as result and not a plot. The `climates` package seemed to provide this in R, but it does not work in R 2.13 anymore.

Is there another way/package to interpolate in R the way I want?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the `akima` package's `interp`.

> These functions implement bivariate interpolation onto a grid for irregularly spaced input data. Bilinear or bicubic spline interpolation is applied using different versions of algorithms from Akima.
>
> Usage
>
> interp(x, y, z, xo=seq(min(x), max(x), length = 40),
>          yo=seq(min(y), max(y), length = 40),
>          linear = TRUE, extrap=FALSE, duplicate = "error", dupfun =
>   NULL, ncp = NULL)

I assume it will work if your data is regularly spaced as well.

Comment: This worked fine within R. I still have problems on how to export the data in x,y,z notation. I'd appreciate if someone could comment on this

Comment: I believe something like `i <- interp (x, y, z)` followed by `c <- cbind (expand.grid (i$x, i$y), c(i$z))` and if you want nice names `colnames (c) <- c("x", "y", "z")` is close. I might have gotten the x and y reversed, so check that.

Comment: the expand.grip function did the trick. I still don't quite understand the meaning of it but I will try to give it a read.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `image.smooth` in the `fields` package.

Comment: Judging by the name, that's probably doing smoothing, not interpolation - the difference being whether the original points are preserved exactly, or not.

Answer (score -1):

To export the data you have interpolated , you could use the follow way:

```
model <- interp(x, y, z, xo=seq(min(x), max(x), length = 40), yo=seq(min(y),
    max(y), length = 40), linear = TRUE, extrap=FALSE, duplicate = "error", 
    dupfun = NULL, ncp = NULL)
interpData <- model$z
```

Load the follow libraries

```
library(rJava)
library(xlsxjars)
library(xlsx)
```

Export your interpolated data in Excel with title multivariateInterp in your hard disc

```
write.xlsx (interpData, "c:/multivariateInterp.xlsx")
```

Comment: Uncertain whether the question was modified, but at the moment this answer does not address the question. Please modify